# .NET Core Entity Framework Core: when using take, how to get totalrecords as well

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework Core.

```
var orglist = _dbContext.Organization
                        .Where(c => c.OrgName.ToLower().Contains(searchBusinessText))
                        .ToList().Take(100);
```

How do I indicate to the users that there are more than 100 hundred records based on their search criteria and that user should try to narrow down the search?

I only need to alert user if the search condition has more records.

Comment: Can't you just `.Count()` after `.ToList()` and before `.Take(100)` to get the total?
Something like `var orglist = _dbContext.Organization.Where(c => c.OrgName.ToLower().Contains(searchBusinessText)).ToList()` To get the count you just use `orglist.Count()` and to get the original result you use `orglist.Take(100)`

Comment: yes i can, but i am concerned about the performance, i have huge database , though it is indexed, was thinking if one call can do it.

Comment: Fetch 101 rows ( `.Take(101)`) - if you really get 101 rows - there are more than 100 rows to be fetched. You can then grab the first 100 of those 101 to return